# Vuetify input color property works only when focused

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm trying to understand how Vuetify's input `color` property is working and I can't find it in [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/inputs), which simply states:

> `color`
>
> *Applies specified color to the control - it can be the name of material color (for example `success` or `purple`) or css color (`#033` or `rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)`). You can find list of built in classes on the colors page.*

What I'm observing is that the `color` has effect only when the control has focus [[LIVE DEMO]](https://codepen.io/rustyx/pen/bGGerde?editors=1010), and goes back to default color when the control loses focus.

```html
<v-text-field color="orange" label="label" />
```

Focused:

[image: Focused]

Not focused:

[image: Not focused]

Is this by design, and is it specified anywhere?

Most importantly, how to affect the `color` of the **not-focused** state (preferably without custom CSS)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the default color to v-text-field use the following css

-- #ff9800 (equivalenyt to orange color)

Working codepen is here https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/ZEEOXKN

```
.theme--light.v-text-field>.v-input__control>.v-input__slot:before {
    border-color: #ff9800;
}

.theme--light.v-label {
    color: #ff9800;
}

.theme--light.v-input:not(.v-input--is-disabled) input, .theme--light.v-input:not(.v-input--is-disabled) textarea {
    color: #ff9800;
}
```

Github issue in vuetify https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/3430

Comment: I was hoping for a less invasive CSS. But this works.